# Laravel: Sentry won't check if user is logged in

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, cartalyst-sentry

While using the Sentry bundle, I created the `LoginController` controller to check if a user is logged in where they are redirected in case they're not. My intention is to extend all my restricted pages to this class to make my code more efficient. But why won't it work?

Login controller:

```
// Extends the BaseController
class LoginController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct() {
        if(!Sentry::check()) return Redirect::to('login');
    }

}
```

My actual controller:

```
class MainController extends LoginController {

    public function getIndex() {

        if(Sentry::getUser()->hasAccess('view dashboard')) {
            return View::make('admin.index');
        } else {
            return 'You have no access!';
        }
    }

}
```

The error I always get:

```
Call to a member function hasAccess() on a non-object
```

**What works:** If I add `if(!Sentry::check()) return Redirect::to('login');` directly in `getIndex()` instead of `__construct`, the redirection works fine. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Notice the typo! __contruct is missing an s.

Answer (score 0):

The Way I see it is __construct() method will only be called when it is initialized. In your case you are extending it not initializing it.If you do something like this it might work.

```
class MainController extends LoginController {
public function __construct()

{

   return parent::__construct();
}

public function getIndex() {

        if(Sentry::getUser()->hasAccess('view dashboard')) {
            return View::make('admin.index');
        } else {
            return 'You have no access!';
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this but it still didn't work. I got the same error `Call to a member function hasAccess() on a non-object`. I got a problem on my code when the User is `not logged in` but when the User is logged in, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think also that problem is

```
public function __construct()
{

   parent::__construct();
}
```

You will call the construct of parent class if you want to execute it

Comment: We already tried this but it didn't work. Probably because the `__contruct` method is only for object creation.

Comment: @Josk79 __contruct is missing an s,

That is a mistake. Fix that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you're not logged in?

You might need something like [this](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/users/find#get-the-current-logged-in-user)

```
try
{
    // Get the current active/logged in user
    $user = Sentry::getUser();
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e)
{
    // User wasn't found, should only happen if the user was deleted
    // when they were already logged in or had a "remember me" cookie set
    // and they were deleted.
}
```